# Как правильно реализовать рестарт игры в данном коде?

Tags: python, pygame

Я практически создал игру, однако я не могу реализовать до сих пор рестарт игры, чтобы игрок мог заново начать игру. Я просматривал сайты, где находился ответ на мой вопрос, но то ли я не понял, как это сделать, то ли он не подходил просто. Пожалуйста, покажите, как это реализовать, когда нажимаешь на определённые кнопки. Буду очень благодарен! Вот мой код с уровнем Очень легко(другие не буду показывать: слишком огромный код):

```
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame
import os
import random
import time

WIDTH = 1300
vec = pygame.math.Vector2
SPEED_SONIC = 0.85
a = 0.5
FRIC = -0.12
HEIGHT = 650
FPS = 60

BLACK_GREEN = (0,128,128)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Survival with Sonic")
# Там ссылки на все изображения, звуки, музыку и шрифт текста

ADDENEMY = pygame.USEREVENT + 3
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDENEMY, 4000)
ADDPLATFORM_1 = pygame.USEREVENT + 4
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDPLATFORM_1, 3550)
ADDPLATFORM_2 = pygame.USEREVENT + 5
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDPLATFORM_2, 4575)
ADDPLATFORM_3 = pygame.USEREVENT + 6
pygame.time.set_timer(ADDPLATFORM_3, 5125)

health = 4

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = player_img
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK_GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.score = 0
        self.plus = 3
        self.pos = vec((100, 300))
        self.vel = vec(0,0)
        self.acc = vec(0,0)

    def update(self):
        self.acc = vec(0, 0.2)
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -SPEED_SONIC
        if keystate[K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = SPEED_SONIC

        self.acc.x += self.vel.x * FRIC
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc  
        self.rect.midbottom = self.pos 

        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

        hits_1 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, platforms1, False)
        if player.vel.y > 0:
            if hits_1:
                if self.pos.y < hits_1[0].rect.bottom:               
                    self.pos.y = hits_1[0].rect.top +1
                    self.vel.y = 0
        hits_2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, platforms2, False)
        if player.vel.y > 0:
            if hits_2:
                if self.pos.y < hits_2[0].rect.bottom:               
                    self.pos.y = hits_2[0].rect.top +1
                    self.vel.y = 0
        hits_3 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, platforms3, False)
        if player.vel.y > 0:
            if hits_3:
                if self.pos.y < hits_3[0].rect.bottom:               
                    self.pos.y = hits_3[0].rect.top +1
                    self.vel.y = 0
        hits_4 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, platform4)
        if self.vel.y > 0:        
            if hits_4:
                if 0 < self.pos.y < platform4.rect.bottom:               
                    self.pos.y = platform4.rect.top +1
                    self.vel.y = 0
        hits_5 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, platform5)
        if player.vel.y > 0:
            if hits_5:
                if 0 < self.pos.y < platform5.rect.bottom:               
                    self.pos.y = platform5.rect.top +1
                    self.vel.y = 0
        hits_6 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, platform6)
        if player.vel.y > 0:
            if hits_6:
                if 0 < self.pos.y < platform6.rect.bottom:               
                    self.pos.y = platform6.rect.top +1
                    self.vel.y = 0
        hits_7 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, platform7)
        if player.vel.y > 0:
            if hits_7:
                if 0 < self.pos.y < platform7.rect.bottom:               
                    self.pos.y = platform7.rect.top +1
                    self.vel.y = 0
        hits_8 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, platform8)
        if player.vel.y > 0:
            if hits_8:
                if 0 < self.pos.y < platform8.rect.bottom:               
                    self.pos.y = platform8.rect.top +1
                    self.vel.y = 0

    def jump(self):
        hits1 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platforms1, False)
        if hits1:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 1.7
        hits2 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platforms2, False)
        if hits2:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 1.7
        hits3 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, platforms3, False)
        if hits3:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 1.7
        hits4 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, platform4)
        if hits4:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 1.7
        hits5 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, platform5)
        if hits5:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 1.7
        hits6 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, platform6)
        if hits6:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 1.7
        hits7 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, platform7)
        if hits7:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 1.7
        hits8 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, platform8)
        if hits8:
            self.vel.y = -15 // 1.7

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(pictures_mouse[0])
        self.images.append(pictures_mouse[1])
        self.images.append(pictures_mouse[2])
        self.images.append(pictures_mouse[3])
        self.index = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(WIDTH, WIDTH)
        self.rect.centery = random.randint(150, HEIGHT - 200)
        self.show = False

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-2, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()
        
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= 120:
            self.index = 0
        
        self.image = self.images[self.index // 30]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
            
class Platform1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = platform_images[0]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(WIDTH, WIDTH)
        self.rect.centery = random.randrange(500, 275, -75)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Platform2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = platform_images[1]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(WIDTH, WIDTH)
        self.rect.centery = random.randrange(400, 200, -75)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Platform3(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = platform_images[2]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = random.randint(WIDTH, WIDTH)
        self.rect.centery = random.randrange(300, 100, -50)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Platform4(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = platform_images[3]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 300
        self.rect.centery = 500

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Platform5(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = platform_images[4]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 550
        self.rect.centery = 425

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Platform6(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = platform_images[5]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 750
        self.rect.centery = 350

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Platform7(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = platform_images[4]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 950
        self.rect.centery = 425

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Platform8(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = platform_images[3]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 1200
        self.rect.centery = 500

    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-1, 0)
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Fire(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fire, self).__init__()
        self.images = []
        self.images.append(pictures_fire[0])
        self.images.append(pictures_fire[1])
        self.images.append(pictures_fire[2])
        self.index1 = 0
        self.image = self.images[self.index1]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH // 2
        self.rect.centery = HEIGHT - 65

        
    def update(self):
        self.index1 += 1
        if self.index1 >= 75:
            self.index1 = 0
        
        self.image = self.images[self.index1 // 25]
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.inactive_color = (75, 0, 130)
        self.active_color = (148, 0, 211)

    def draw(self, x, y, message, action = None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if x < mouse[0] < x + self.width and y < mouse[1] < y + self.height:
             pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.active_color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))

             if click[0] == 1:
                 pygame.time.delay(100)
                 pygame.mixer.Sound.play(mouse_sound)
                 if action is not None:
                     action()

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.inactive_color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))

        print_text_5(message, x + 10, y + 10)

class Button2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.inactive_color = (75, 0, 130)
        self.active_color = (148, 0, 211)

    def draw(self, x, y, message, action = None):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        if x < mouse[0] < x + self.width and y < mouse[1] < y + self.height:
             pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.active_color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))

             if click[0] == 1:
                 pygame.time.delay(100)
                 pygame.mixer.Sound.play(mouse_sound)
                 if action is not None:
                     action()

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.inactive_color, (x, y, self.width, self.height))

        print_text_6(message, x + 10, y + 10)

class QuitState:
    quit = False
    def set_quit():
        QuitState.quit = True

def show_health():
    global health
    show = 0
    x = 20
    while show != health:
        screen.blit(health_png,(x, 20))
        health_png.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        x += 50
        show += 1

# Там присваивание всех классов и групп + функции написания текстов 

def beginning():
    Beginning = True
    while Beginning and not QuitState.quit:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit() 
    
        mini_button = Button(230, 80)
        screen.blit(important_phone_jpg, important_phone_rect)
        print_text_5('Выживание с Соником', 320, 50)
        mini_button.draw(535, 170, 'Играть', game1)
        mini_button1 = Button(440, 80)
        pygame.display.update()

def game1():
    pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(folder2, ('music_for_game1.mp3')))
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
    global health 
    Game = True
    while Game and not QuitState.quit:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:    
                if event.key == K_SPACE:
                    player.jump()
                    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(jump_sound)
            elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
                new_enemy = Enemy()
                enemies.add(new_enemy)
                all_sprites.add(new_enemy)
            elif event.type == ADDPLATFORM_1:
                new_platform1 = Platform1()
                platforms1.add(new_platform1)
                all_sprites.add(new_platform1)
            elif event.type == ADDPLATFORM_2:
                new_platform2 = Platform2()
                platforms2.add(new_platform2)
                all_sprites.add(new_platform2)
            elif event.type == ADDPLATFORM_3:
                new_platform3 = Platform3()
                platforms3.add(new_platform3)
                all_sprites.add(new_platform3)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit()  

        if player.score <= -1:
            player.score = 0

        hits_4 = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemies, True)
        if hits_4:
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(enemy_sound)
            health -= 1
            player.score -= 20
             
        hits_5 = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player, fire) 
        if hits_5:
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(fire_sound)
            health -= health
            
        if player.score >= 900:
            pygame.mixer.Sound.play(win_sound)
            victory1()

        if health <= 0:
            game_over1()
            
        show_health()
        button = Button(195,80)
        button.draw(20, 80, 'Пауза', pause1)
        print_text('Очки  ' + str(player.score), 725, 25)
        print_text(':', 840, 25)
        pygame.display.update()
        all_sprites.update()
        screen.blit(morning_png, morning_rect)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

def pause1():
    Pause = True
    while Pause and not QuitState.quit:
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit()  
                
        screen.blit(phone_jpg, phone_rect)
        buttonq = Button(120, 80)
        print_text_2('Хотите продолжить игру?', 400, 270)
        buttonq.draw(300, 340, 'Да!', game1)
        buttonq_1 = Button(140, 80)
        buttonq_1.draw(870, 340, 'Нет!', beginning)
        pygame.display.update()

def game_over1():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    Game_over = True
    while not QuitState.quit:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit() 
                
        screen.blit(game_over_jpg, game_over_rect)
        button_5 = Button(235,80)
        print_text_3('К сожалению, вы проиграли! Попробуйте ещё раз!', 135, 400)
        button_5.draw(400, 500, 'Заново', game1)
        button_5.draw(700, 500, 'Назад', beginning)
        pygame.display.update()
        
def victory1():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    Victory = True
    while Victory and not QuitState.quit:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                QuitState.set_quit()
            
        screen.blit(victory_jpg, victory_rect)
        button_5 = Button(205,90)
        print_text('Ура! Вы победили! Мои поздравления! Хотите сыграть ещё раз?', 280, 360)
        button_5.draw(450, 500, 'Да', game1)
        button_5.draw(650, 500, 'Нет', beginning)
        pygame.display.update()        
        pygame.display.update()     
        clock.tick(FPS)

beginning()
pygame.quit()
```